# ASP.Net Ajax - UpdateProgress Sleep

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, updateprogress

Getting to grips with ASP.Net Ajax

I've got a simple UpdatePanel with an associated UpdateProgress which I'm using to tell a user their shopping cart has been added to.

Is it OK to use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); in the code behind so the user can actually see the UpdateProgress? Or is this bad practice? If it is what's the best thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad practice, if the user is on a slow connection you are going to make them wait an extra 5 seconds for an update.

If you wish to show someone the loading screen do a shorter wait like .5 of a second.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```